# final output of Result, in F#

Tags: f#

This seems like a question that has an ultra simple answer, but I can't think of it:

Is there a built in method, within Result, for:

```
let (a: Result<'a, 'a>) = ...
match a with
| Ok x    -> x
| Error e -> e
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but this doesn’t seem like something that would be useful very often. Do you have an example of when this would be helpful?

Comment: yes, for example with the Suave webserver: everything is the same object, whether it's a successful response, or an error. So I can define a chain of events bound to each other with a computation expression and, in the end, I collect an object which is the result, or the same object showing an error. But having result as an intermediate type allows me to use the expression instead of a bunch of nested ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any function which will allow you to do so. But you can easily define it:

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Result =
    let join (value: Result<'a, 'a>) =
         match value with
         | Ok v -> v
         | Error e -> e

let getResult s =
    if System.String.IsNullOrEmpty s then
        Error s
    else 
        Ok s

let a =
   getResult "asd"
   |> Result.join
   |> printfn "%s"
```

It doesn't make `Result` less general (as said by @brianberns), because it's not an instance member. Existence of [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap) doesn't make `Task` less general

#### Update

After more scrupulous searching inside FSharpPlus and FSharpx.Extras I've found necessary function. It's signature `('a -> 'c) -> ('b -> 'c) -> Result<'a,'b> -> c` instead of `Result<'a, 'a> -> 'a` and it's called `Result.either` in both libraries ([source 1](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus/blob/9ce1279b62be4bb71f65646960f8282a355625e3/src/FSharpPlus/Extensions/Result.fs#L62) and [source 2](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/7f0610e00698523f412f384c417e87ad34b10f0f/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Result.fs#L97)). So in order to get value we may pass `id` as both parameters:

```ml
#r "nuget:FSharpPlus"
open FSharpPlus
// OR
#r "nuget:FSharpx.Extras"
open FSharpx

getResult "asd"
|> Result.either id id
|> printfn "%s"
```

Also it's may be useful to define shortcut and call it `Result.join` or `Result.fromEither` as it's [called](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Either+a+a+-%3E+a&scope=set%3Astackage) in Haskell

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply it has some sort of global effect on `Result`. I just mean that it's not part of the standard `Result` module because it only works when the types are the same.

Comment: That’s the same I posted in the question, I was just wondering if there was a utility function already built for such a case

Comment: @Thomas, I've found this function in third-party libraries, check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

No, because this function requires the `Ok` type and the `Error` type to be the same, which makes `Result` less general.